# How does Altium designer decide the size of the solder mask?

Tags: altium, footprint

Here is a footprint I created using the footprint wizard in Altium designer.

[image]

The red is top layer pad. The purple is the top solder mask. Whenever I change the top copper pad size, the solder mask pad size changes with it. It is not possible change the two independantly.

1. Why is it not possible to change the size of the solder mask independantly from the copper pad?
2. How does Altium decide how big to make the solder mask from the copper pad?

Comment: Look at the solder mask expansion property of the pad.

Comment: Altium has its own forum for these questions: https://forum.live.altium.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the sizes in the Pad Properties panel under **Solder (and Paste) Mask Expansion**. There are two options:

[image: Altium Designer - Pad Properties]

1. Rule based
2. Manual

If you choose rules based (default), then the design rules affect the expansion:

[image: Altium Designer - DRC for SolderMask]

For more information consult the [official documentation](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-pad-properties).

Comment: SolderMaskExpansion rule, I see. That is what I was looking for. I can open rules when I am in the PCB editor window by going to Design -> Rules. But this option is missing when I am in the PCB footprint editor. Can the rules window be opened from the PCB footprint wizard too?

Comment: @Quantum Ah that's a good question. According to [Creating a PCB Footprint in Altium Designer](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/creating-pcb-footprint): "Altium Designer automatically adds solder and paste masks to pad objects based on their shape. Default expansion values are defined by design rules by default, although they can also be specified by the Pad settings contained on the PCB Editor - Defaults page of the Preferences dialog. These settings can be overridden during placement or after placement through the Properties panel."

Comment: @Quantum Personally I didn't find that terribly helpful. Even in the preferences -> defaults, the "rule" option disables editing of the value. I presume that the manual values entered in preferences are what the footprint editor uses, but the actual amounts change when the footprint is subjected to DRC of a given PCB.